# Best choice for a holding large number of objects in java

Tags: java, array, search

I have a set of array, containing a large number of objects (products), which has lately grown so large, searching in it takes about a minute, which is considered too long, since one search is expected at every minute.

I'm looking for a way to reformat the engine for a more modern/faster one. The objects does have a unique identifier (alphabet+numbers, stored as one String, it's named "aid"), and it is expected to be used as the primary way of identification, since it remains the same across all databases (renames happen sometimes).

There are 3 Strings that can be searched, but these are not unique (like name, different products can have the same name, like 'Empty CD'). During updates and inserts, "aid" is used for identification. When I get data from the database, like a new element was inserted or updated, I must change it in Java online, and repaint the display accordingly. Up until now, it was checking an array for duplication, if there was, it updated, or it was inserted. There will be no deletion (it's handled differently).

I also need it to be displayed in a JList, but it has it's own CellRenderer, along with the product objects own toString(); method.

I was thinking about some sort of a tree, preferably the Red-Black tree, since it gives a good result in maximum search time, (like, 16 hops at most right now) however, I can't really order it by key. (Like, if it's ordered by "aid", I can update it from the database, but I can't search it by "name").

In short, display is by JList (array of objects right now).
There is going to be update and insert by "aid", but no deletion.
The objects have 3 Strings to be searched for, but not by "aid".
"aid" needs to be the primary way of unique identification, as the 3 Strings mentioned above are not necessarily unique.

So I think I need a structure that can be searched by multiple unordered Strings at the same time.

Comment: Three separate Maps or Multimaps?

Comment: I haven't really do the calculations, separate Maps might be good if the don't use a lot of memory, I need to check multimaps more thoroughly, thanks.

Comment: Do you need only to speed up exact searches for those 3 strings, or also searches with arbitrary patterns?

Comment: Only for those 3 strings, I want to search only simple substrings within them.

Comment: @user949300 I don't think multimaps would work well in this case, but four separate maps just might work, and I can even update all four at the same time. I will go along with it for now.